# London Stock Exchange Company News, recent changes to website disrupt acquisition of RNS from website , need new way to get the news

Tags: web-scraping, feed, stock

Recently the London Stock Exchange website has changed.
It was possible to get the links to the RNS news for each company by parsing the html on,  for example,

'https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news?tab=news-explorer&sources=RNS&period=lastweek'

and looking for company tickers such as SHEL  or BDEV, or  other indicators of interest in the HTML e.g.  newsitem  . From there  extract, from the HTML, the link to the RNS (regulatory news item) and consequently download the news item for further examination.

Now this is not possible , the data is blocked company tickers and the like do not appear in the source.

The RNS news is essential for investors and whether large or small there should be equal access. Some days there are a great number of RNS and by only by downloading is it possible for the small investor to scan them to find news items relevant to their investing strategy in the hour before the market opens.

Can anyone help with a method to regain access to RNS news?

P.S. If I haven't put this question in the correct place, or if there is something wrong with it please tell me as I haven't written many questions before.

Comment: Can you confirm the new url, and what specific data you need from there?

Comment: I am looking for links like this one https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/API/purchase-of-own-ordinary-shares/15574524

Answer (score 1):

I had a look over that url, and I'm not really sure how you will move forward on this one, tbh. I expected you have some sort of list of articles, which could be used on some sort of scraping scaffold. Nonetheless, given that url you provided, this is one way you could go around it -check Dev tools - Network tab, and see if any XHR calls are being    made, to some api; if you found one, you scrape that api endpoint, like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://api.londonstockexchange.com/api/v1/pages?path=news-article&parameters=newsId%253D15574524'

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())
```

This returns a rather large json object, which you can dissect and get the information you need. For example:

```
html = r.json()['components'][1]['content'][0]['value']['body']
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('title').get_text(strip=True))
print(soup.select_one('body').get_text(strip=True))
```

As long as you would have a list of '`newsId`'s, you could scrape the info for every such `newsId`, modifying the api endpoint used above. This prints in terminal:

```
Purchase of Own Ordinary Shares
8 August 2022abrdn Property Income Trust Limited (“the Company”)Legal Entity Identifier (LEI): 549300HHFBWZRKC7RW84PURCHASE OF OWN ORDINARY SHARESOn 5 August 2022 the Company purchased 345,935 Ordinary Shares at a price of 79.07 pence per share. These shares will be held in treasury.Following the transaction, the Company’s issued ordinary share capital comprises:386,018,977 Issued Ordinary shares (excluding treasury....
```